I need to fiind a drain cover or screen for this old garage drain
The outer ring is 4 inches diameter and the hole is 2 inches diameter.
I don't know if an exact match is possible but if not, is there something else I could put inside it?
You can see a picture below.
I found this 4 inch "cast-strainer" https://www.plumbingsupply.com/images/cast-strainer-cover-heavy-duty-sp-8n-polished-nickeland.jpg Does anyone think it will match?


That looks like a cast iron shower drain. There are several common sizes and replacement grates should be available at a plumbing shop. Unfortunately, it appears that the screw holes have either been destroyed or filled in with something... so you will need to address that. Or use a "stab in" retrofit grate, they have prongs that stick down and you basically just jam them down in. Nobody can tell you if the one in the linked picture will work, because there are no dimensions included...

Here is the link where I found this drain cover. https://www.plumbingsupply.com/replacement-floor-drain-covers.html

You need to determine if your drain's screw holes are viable before you consider a screw down strainer. Also, you need to measure the distance between the center of the two screw holes.
